# Get Last Sales dates and Sales Amount for a Date Range in MDX

Tags: mdx

I need to get the LastSalesDate with SalesAmount for a date range. But the following MDX is not filtered by date range. Other Data is OK.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[MaxSaleDate] 
    AS 
        TAIL(
            FILTER(
                [Date—Date].[Date].MEMBERS, 
                NOT ISEMPTY([Measures].[Sales])
            )
        ).ITEM(0).NAME

SELECT { [Measures].[MaxSaleDate], NONEMPTY([Measures].[Sales]) } ON COLUMNS,
       { [Store—Store].[Store].MEMBERS * [Store-NoOfDaysSales].[NoOfDays].MEMBERS } ON ROWS
FROM ( SELECT (  
           [Date—Date].[All Date—Date].[2012-10-14 00:00:00.000] :  
           [Date—Date].[All Date—Date].[2012-11-14 00:00:00.000]
       ) ON COLUMNS 
       FROM [Sales])
```

Thanks. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter statement is picking all dates in your date dimension instead of the filter.  You also have an unnecessary subcube in your where.

```
WITH

MEMBER [Measures].[MaxSaleDate] AS
TAIL(FILTER([Date—Date].[All Date—Date].[2012-10-14 00:00:00.000] :
            [Date—Date].[All Date—Date].[2012-11-14 00:00:00.000],
            NOT ISEMPTY([Measures].[Sales])
            )
      ).ITEM(0).Name

SELECT { [Measures].[MaxSaleDate], NONEMPTY([Measures].[Sales]) } ON COLUMNS,
{ [Store—Store].[Store].MEMBERS * [Store-NoOfDaysSales].[NoOfDays].MEMBERS } ON ROWS
FROM [Sales]
WHERE [Date—Date].[All Date—Date].[2012-10-14 00:00:00.000] :
      [Date—Date].[All Date—Date].[2012-11-14 00:00:00.000]
```